# Must the orientation of a parameterized curve $\gamma:I\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be in the direction of the increasing parameter?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves, line-integrals

In the context of evaluating the line integral of a vector field $\vec{F}:\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \vec{F}(\vec{x})\in\mathbb{R}^n$ along a regular parameterized curve $\gamma:t\in{I}\subseteq\mathbb{R}\mapsto \vec{x}(t)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we define $$\int_{\gamma}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{x} = \int_{I}\vec{F} \left(\vec{x}(t)\right)\cdot \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}(t)dt$$

I have learned that this definition ensures its invariance under an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism $\tau:t\in I \mapsto \tau(t)\in I'$ since the chain rule provides that $$\frac{d\vec{x}}{d\tau} (t(\tau)) = \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} (t(\tau)) \frac{dt}{d\tau} (\tau)$$ and the change in measure introduces a factor $\lvert{\frac{dt}{d\tau}(\tau)}\rvert$ such that $$\int_{\gamma} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{x} = \int_{I'}\vec{F}(\vec{x}(t(\tau))) \cdot \left[\frac{\frac{d\vec{x}}{d\tau}(t(\tau))} {\frac{dt}{d\tau}(\tau)}\right] \lvert \frac{dt}{d\tau}(\tau)\rvert d\tau = \int_{I'}\vec{F} \left(\vec{x}(t(\tau))\right)\cdot \frac{d\vec{x}}{d\tau}(t(\tau))d\tau$$ This seems to crucially rely on $\frac{dt}{d\tau}(\tau)$ being positive on $I'$ or equivalently $\frac{d\tau}{dt}(t)$ being positive on $I$, which I took to be the definition of $\tau(t)$ being an orientation-preserving reparameterization of the regular curve $\gamma$. Since $\frac{d\vec{x}}{d\tau} (t(\tau)) = \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} (t(\tau)) \frac{dt}{d\tau} (\tau)$, I have noted that this is equivalent to the tangent vectors being parallel at any given point along the curve.

My confusion then comes from what is meant by orientation.

It seems that the orientation of $\gamma$ could equally be defined as being along the direction that the parameter decreases (antiparallel to the tangent vector) instead of the direction that the parameter increases (parallel to the tangent vector). Both are compatible with the notion of orientation-preserving reparameterizations. Is orientation independent of parameterization? For simple curves, does the notation$\int_{\gamma}$ only refer to integrating over the image $\{\gamma(t)\vert t\in I\}$ or the family of parameterizations of the image $\{\gamma(t)\vert t\in I\}$ with a particular orientation? If so, it is more correct to write $$\int_{\gamma}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{x} = \pm \int_{I}\vec{F} \left(\vec{x}(t)\right)\cdot \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}(t)dt$$ where $\pm$ is chosen such that the orientation of $\gamma$ is in the direction of increasing $\pm t$?

For example, suppose I wanted to integrate some vector field $\vec{F}:\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3\mapsto \vec{F}(\vec{x})\in\mathbb{R}^3$ along the straight line segment connecting $(1,1,1)$ to the origin, starting from $(1,1,1)$ and ending at $(0,0,0)$. If we define $\gamma:t\in[0,1]\mapsto (t,t,t)\in \mathbb{R}^3$, would this line integral still be denoted $\int_{\gamma}\vec{F}(\vec{x}) \cdot d\vec{x}$ or would it be necessary to write $-\int_{\gamma}\vec{F}(\vec{x}) \cdot d\vec{x}$ or even $\int_{-\gamma}\vec{F}(\vec{x}) \cdot d\vec{x}$, where $-\gamma:t\in[0,1]\mapsto (1-t,1-t,1-t)\in \mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: I think in the case of Calculus 3, it would be most accurate to denote your last integral as $\int_{-\gamma} F(x)\cdot dx$, which is of course equal to $-\int_\gamma F(x)\cdot dx$. In a more general context, the *definition* of the curve $\gamma$ comes bundled with an orientation-consistent family of parameterizations, and you can compute $\int_{\gamma} F(x)\cdot dx$ using any of these parameterizations. This prevents any confusion about the notation $\int_{\gamma}$, as the orientation is a part of the data of $\gamma$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @WhileIAm (and the edit @FD_bfa)! To check my understanding, is it possible for a parameterization to have an orientation in the direction its parameter decreases while still being in the orientation-consistent family of parameterizations associated with $\gamma$? In terms of my example, would the parameterizations $\pm \gamma$ with orientations in the direction of decreasing $\pm t$ both belong to the bundle for the straight line from $(1,1,1)$ to the origin (despite the lower sign be used as the defining representative by convention)?

Comment: My above comment is too brief to be an answer. If I have time tomorrow I'll write up something detailed which answers your questions. This is well known, so they may be answered before then!